Consul for service discovery on docker swarm
I understand this may be an old item to discuss. Yet, I have not come across any proper document to answer my query
Context
We have 18 VMs running monolith applications and databases. 12 apps are candidate to move to a new 3 node docker swarm setup (docker ce). The swarm is deployed on air-gapped environment, hence private registry and images are used. The network is heavily dependent on the on-prem AD for existing service naming. There's a mix of other VMs in other 4 VM infra (16 physical servers running 48 VMs, mostly Windows, BSD and Solaris). The network is 10g end-to-end (if this helps) and current utilization is around 3% during peak hours. Not bringing up the DMZ here, since the extension of this docker swarm will be done for DMZ too.
Kubernetes is not an option here due to complexity (also I am more fluent in vanilla docker), since one guy (that's me) is managing the infra (network, FW, servers, storage, Linux/UNIX), deployments. Also gitlab for upcoming pipeline for the new env.
We want to gradually move the 12 apps to the swarm in 3 batches, dependent on their relation with each other. Timeline for 1st phase to complete UAT is 20th May 2024.

There's no way to re-write apps,
Binaries, configs and volumes will moved to images, and
There's no direct dependency on IPs, as either it's /etc/hosts or the DNS helping with the names
Consul is running on all 3 docker hosts directly on the host, rather than in docker. Cluster setup is on all 3 hosts. No envoy setup yet. Consul's DNS is also enabled on port 53, while UI and other grpc ports kept as-is.

Problem
We want to us the consul's DNS for all services running in docker swarm. We want to pass the DNS config on the docker. However, since there's no way to re-write the code, we want to ensure the services are registered dynamically on consul, so that its discoverable from other dockers running. We can use sidecar proxy for this, but there's just no proper documentation for our use case. Also, we're not sure if we need sidecar at all, since we're going to rely on consul's DNS and forwarding to AD for other legacy/non-docker services.
Also, we're running on debian 12, hence no OEMs are involved in this.
Please help!

docker swarm literally has service discovery built into its own dns. with virtual lips and load balancing.

Only in isolated network, because otherwise I couldn't get the DNS working


we want to ensure the services are registered dynamically on consul, so that its discoverable from other dockers running.

Registrator can be used to automatically register Docker containers into Consul. The project hasn't seen a lot of updates as of late, but as far as I know it still works so it should be a viable option.

Tried it out. Problem with it is the tags and services in the swarm deployment doesn't work
